# optimizing multiple calls to RESTful service

Tags: .net, rest, service, web

I need to call a RESTful web service multiple times from a C# client code. I don't have the luxury of switching to .Net 4.0 yet - is there a way to achieve this in .Net 3.5?

The calls are all to the same method, just with different parameters. I need to wait till all the calls are completed before I can proceed with the rest of my logic.

I have been looking at RX backported to 3.5, but am not sure if I will be allowed to use it. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Try out http://restsharp.org/, it is a REST API consumer for .NET 3.5+